# Database software for a personal budget

Tags: database, database-browser

I need a database for my personal budget.

Features:

- Supports a decent SQL flavour (regexes would be great...)
- Easy way to sync to multiple PCs (web based, or, ideally, persisted as a file)
- Support for Windows, Mac and Linux (natively or web)
- Robust reporting, particularly graphs
- Forms would be useful

I started with various tools like YNAB and Pocketsmith and they were not flexible enough. I then went to a spreadsheet and that was much better, but I kept thinking "I wish I could just write a bloody SQL query".

Ideally I would like an embedded/file database such as LibreOffice Base (HSQLDB, Firebird), SQLite, Access (Jet) so that it will persist via a file that will seamlessly sync via Dropbox. I would also like some way to view the data and also create queries/reports/graphs.

I would welcome any suggestions (a DB & manager/browser, or any novel solution) people have!

I've tried a HSQLDB-backed LibreOffice Base DB, since it meets all of these requirements pretty well. Unfortunately I ran into an issue where regex is not supported by HSQLDB and I was unable to migrate to Firebird due to several bugs in Base.

Comment: Have you looked at Kexi? http://www.kexi-project.org/about.html

Comment: Thanks @EricShain, it looks pretty close but unfortunately Windows and Mac versions are not yet offered.

Comment: You can setup mysql/mariadb.  Then connect to it from LibreBase via ODBC or JDBC.

Comment: @Will: There is past version of Kexi that was adapted for Windows by Stefan Roehrach. See https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=221&t=110012#p358395 Kexi is flexible, but you will have to build your app yourself. I'm also not sure if you can plot graphs with it.